# Numerical solution to a differential equation - approximating using tridiagonal matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

So my task is to solve this differential equation:
$$y''(x) + \frac{9.8}{0.7} y(x) = 0,~~ y(0) =0.1, y'(15) = \frac{\pi}{12}.$$ 
I need to solve it numerically. I made substitutions and I solve it using Euler's methods.

The problem is, I need to solve it using a system of linear equations that have a tridiagonal matrix (It's written in the task, that I need to solve it this way). I don't know how to create this matrix. Solving it will be easy, I guess. Any tips?

Comment: Note that Mathematica yields the exact solution (useful for comparing with the numerical solution): $$ y(x)=\frac{1}{168} \left(168 c_1 \cos \left(\sqrt{14}
    x\right)+168 c_1 \tan \left(15 \sqrt{14}\right) \sin \left(\sqrt{14}
    x\right)+\sqrt{14} \pi  \sec \left(15 \sqrt{14}\right) \sin \left(\sqrt{14}
    x\right)\right).$$

Comment: Presumably, the point is to approximate the second derivative as a second difference: $$y''(x)\approx \frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{2h^2}$$ if $h$ is small.

Comment: @SimonJackson If you intend to use the forward Euler method, there will be no linear system to solve... It is an explicit method.

Comment: @Semiclassical You have a typo in your formula. The denominator should just be $h^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the central difference approximation:

$$y''(x)\simeq\frac{y(x+h)-2y(x)+y(x-h)}{h^2}$$

to get the system of equations:

$$\frac{y_{i+1}-2y_i+y_{i-1}}{h^2}+\frac{9.8}{0.7}y_i=0$$

and hence the corresponding [tridiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm)

$$Ay=0$$

where

$$A=\operatorname{tridiag}\left(\frac1{h^2},-\dfrac2{h^2}+\dfrac{9.8}{0.7},\frac1{h^2}\right)$$

or, equivalently with fractions cleared a bit:

$$A=\frac1{h^2}\operatorname{tridiag}\left(1,-2+\dfrac{9.8}{0.7}h^2,1\right)$$

Comment: But where do we use the initial conditions ? And does tridiag(a,b,c) means {{b,c,0,0..} , {a,b,c,0...0}, {0.a,b,c,0..} .. {0...,0,a,b} } ?

Comment: Replace the top and bottom rows with {1, 0, 0, ...} and {0, 1, 0, ...}, and replace the corresponding rows of the RHS with $y_0$ and $y_1$, where $y_1$ is computed using Euler's method.

Answer (score 1):

With finite elements you may have to spend more time analyzing the boundary points than the interior points. If we let $x_k=x_0+kh$ where $h=(x_f-x_0)/N$ is the step size for $N$ steps from $x_0$ to $x_f$ and $y_k=y(x_k)$ then for an interior point
$$\begin{align}y_{k-1}&=y_k-hy_k^{\prime}+\frac12h^2y_k^{\prime\prime}-\frac13h^3y_k^{\prime\prime\prime}+O\left(h^4\right)\\
y_k&=y_k\\
y_{k+1}&=y_k+hy_k^{\prime}+\frac12h^2y_k^{\prime\prime}+\frac13h^3y_k^{\prime\prime\prime}+O\left(h^4\right)\end{align}$$
So
$$\frac{y_{k-1}-2y_k+y_{k+1}}{h^2}=y_k^{\prime\prime}+O\left(h^2\right)=-\omega^2y_k+O\left(h^2\right)$$
So the difference equation for an interior point is
$$y_{k-1}+(-2+h^2\omega^2)y_k+y_{k+1}=0$$
Due to the Dirichlet boundary conditions the difference equation at the initial point is
$$y_0=y_0$$
(given). But at the final point we have to construct a difference equation for the first derivative accurate to $O\left(h^2\right)$. So
$$\begin{align}y_{N-2}&=y_N-2hy_N^{\prime}+2h^2y_N^{\prime\prime}+O\left(h^3\right)\\
y_{N-1}&=y_N-hy_N^{\prime}+\frac12h^2y_N^{\prime\prime}+O\left(h^3\right)\\
y_N&=y_N\end{align}$$
So
$$\frac{y_{N-2}-4y_{N-1}+3y_N}{2h}=y_N^{\prime}+O\left(h^2\right)$$
So the difference equation at the final point is
$$y_{N-2}-4y_{N-1}+3y_N=2hy_N^{\prime}$$
But this creates a problem in that the presence of $y_{N-2}$ breaks tridiagonality. We can fix this by a round of Gaussian elimination:
$$\begin{align}y_{N-2}&+(-2+h^2\omega^2)y_{N-1}&+y_N&=0\\
y_{N-2}&-4y_{N-1}&+3y_N&=2hy_N^{\prime}\end{align}$$
Subtract the first equation from the second and tridiagonality is restored. Some Matlab code:

```
% Pendulum.m

N = 400; % Nodes run from 0 to N
x0 = 0;
y0 = 0.1;
xN = 15;
yNp = pi/12;
h = (xN-x0)/N;
x = x0+[0:N]'*h;
omega = sqrt(9.8/0.7);
% Equation for interior point is y(k-1)+(-2+omega^2*h^2)y(k)+y(k+1) = 0
L = ones(N+1,1);
d = ones(N+1,1)*(-2+h^2*omega^2);
u = ones(N+1,1);
y = zeros(N+1,1);
% First row is y(0) = y0
L(1) = 0; % Not used
d(1) = 1;
u(1) = 0;
y(1) = y0;
% Last row is y(N-2)-4y(N-1)+3y(N)=2*h*y'(N)
extra = 1;
L(N+1) = -4;
d(N+1) = 3;
u(N+1) = 0; % Not used
y(N+1) = 2*h*yNp;
% Need one step of Gaussian elimination to make system tridiagonal
temp = extra/L(N);
L(N+1) = L(N+1)-d(N)*temp;
d(N+1) = d(N+1)-u(N)*temp;
y(N+1) = y(N+1)-y(N)*temp;
% Now system is tridiagonal. Sweep down
for k=2:N+1,
    temp = L(k)/d(k-1);
    d(k) = d(k)-u(k-1)*temp;
    y(k) = y(k)-y(k-1)*temp;
end
% Sweep up
y(N+1) = y(N+1)/d(N+1);
for k = N:-1:1,
    y(k) = (y(k)-u(k)*y(k+1))/d(k);
end
% find exact solution
A = [cos(omega*x0) sin(omega*x0);
    -omega*sin(omega*xN) omega*cos(omega*xN)];
b = [y0; yNp*.2618/.2986];
C = A\b;
exact = C(1)*cos(omega*x)+C(2)*sin(omega*x);
% Plot
plot(x,y,'k.',x,exact,'r-');
title('Approximation to Pendulum Problem');
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
legend('Tridiagonal','Exact','Location','best');
```

And the results
[image: Pendulum.png]

Comment: In the last step you could also have used $y_{N-1}=y_N-hy_N'+\frac{h^2}2y_N''+O(h^3)=y_N(1-\frac12h^2ω^2)-hy_N'+O(h^3)$, getting the same result.

Comment: @LutzLehmann True, but normally one is solving a $2$ or higher dimension problem so $\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$ doesn't have a simple expression in terms of the differential equation. As is, my solution requires a lot of points. Do you think I should upgrade it and the Neumann boundary condition with the Numerov stuff to get to $O\left(h^4\right)$? How does it work if the potential (assuming Schrödinger's equation) isn't constant?

Comment: Yes, going 4th order would allow larger step sizes for the same accuracy. One would need some kind of (adapted) interpolation to plot a properly curved solution. // You mean for $y''(x)+q(x)y(x)=0$? The principal approach stays the same, only when inserting the second derivatives in the last step you also get the coefficient evaluated at the neighboring locations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a bit more precise in $y''+ay=0$ than just the second order central difference quotient, write its remainder as
$$
\frac{y(x+h)-2y(x)+y(x-h)}{h^2}=y''(x)+\frac{h^2}{12}y^{\small IV}(x)+O(h^4)
$$
and also approximate the 4th derivative using the second order difference quotient of the second derivative
$$
h^2y^{\small IV}(x)=y''(x+h)-2y''(x)+y''(x-h)+O(h^4)=-a(y(x+h)-2y(x)+y(x-h))+O(h^4)
$$
so that you get the discretized equation
$$
\frac{y(x+h)-2y(x)+y(x-h)}{h^2}+\frac{a}{12}(y(x+h)+10y(x)+y(x-h))=0
$$
which is the Störmer-Cowell-Numerov method (of lowest order). The system matrix is then
$$
\frac1{h^2}{\rm tridiag}\left(1+\frac{ah^2}{12}, -2+\frac{5ah^2}6, 1+\frac{ah^2}{12}\right)
$$